# Integer changing value on its own JS

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

When I put this code into express(using app.get) to feed it to the client side:

```
<script>
  console.log(513181088768720987)
<script>
```

The output should be 513181088768720987, however, it changes the output to 513181088768720960. Also, if I inspect the code I can still see the console.log with the value in it's original state. If I attempt to initialize socket.io and send the value to my server(as a variable) the server receives the variable the same way the console logs it(incorrectly). Any Idea why this happens?

Im using chrome as my browser, and node.js with express to feed the code from a server to the client side

Comment: JavaScript values don't have enough precision to represent that exactly.

Comment: your number is out of range: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#integer_range_for_number

Comment: ok, thank you for the help!